# How to go ahead with the question using SQLworkbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

[image: Dataset]

Note that MR stands for “most recent”:

```
PHA_NAME, 
MR_INSPECTION_DATE, 
MR_INSPECTION_COST,
SECOND_MR_INSPECTION_DATE,
SECOND_MR_INSPECTION_COST,
CHANGE_IN_COST
PERCENT_CHANGE_IN_COST
```

Management has asked that you perform this function using lead or lag functions in SQL.

However, they’re concerned that the files when imported into MySQL Workbench may not properly refer to dates using the correct format. If that is the case, they’ve asked you to investigate how best to convert dates from TEXT to Date format so that the lead/lag functions work as expected.

They’ve also asked that you filter your dataset to only those PHAs that saw an increase in $$ cost, and that you only list the PHA once with no duplicates to avoid noisy data.

Naturally, this would also require you to filter out PHAs that only performed one inspection, so they’ve asked you to remove those as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try? SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: I tried using MAX function but i couldn't get the desired result